# How can I seed and call C++ random number generator from MATLAB mex function?

Tags: c++, matlab, random, mex

I am trying to call a random number generator code (written in C++) from Matlab. I found example of how to write a simple mex function. The way I want to program to function is:

1. first call to set seed.
2. then subsequent calls will keep returning random numbers.

I understand instead of multiple calls, calling the mex function only once is more efficient but I am trying to achieve step 1 and step 2 as described above.

Essentially my custom random number generator will behave like the matlab random number generator. Can someone please give me some pointer as to how to achieve this?

Comment: So you want the RNG's state to be retained across calls to the mex file? That's not really a good use case for mex. You'll probably have to add in a 3rd call type which is to clear state, and register a `mexAtExit` function to clear it automatically. Even with these, it won't be possible to have 2 independent RNGs unless you implement some key-value mechanism. Given that it's so much trouble, you should probably ask yourself why you want to do this in mex. Matlab has built-in RNGs, why are those not good enough for you?

Comment: the purpose of this experiment is two folds:1) is to figure out if this can be achieved or not. 2) i am trying to tie out two computations one performed in c++ and the other in matlab with random number generation involved. i can read in arrays of random in any one of them but that will be involve too many code changes in either matlab or c++. And now when it seems the problem is more difficult it is just triggering my curiosity as to if I can someway achieve writing this custom generator.

Comment: You can try using [`mexMakeMemoryPersistent`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakememorypersistent.html) or [`mexMakeArrayPersistent`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakearraypersistent.html), but be careful not to leak memory (see `mexAtExit`).

Comment: Another way to handle this is to have your mex code take in and return another output that corresponds to the state (not seed) of the random number generator. That way the state can always be set to its value at the end of the previous call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example:

#### myrand.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <cstdlib>

static bool initialized = false;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs != 1 || nlhs > 1)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Wrong number of arguments.");
    if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0])!=1)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Expecting a scalar.");
    double in = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

    if (!initialized) {
        if (nlhs != 0)
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Wrong number of arguments.");
        unsigned int seed = static_cast<unsigned int>(in);
        srand(seed);
        initialized = true;
    }
    else {
        mwSize len = static_cast<mwSize>(in);
        plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(len, 1, mxREAL);
        double *x = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
        for (mwSize i=0; i<len; ++i)
            x[i] = rand()%256;
    }
}
```

Now in MATLAB:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -silent myrand.cpp
>> myrand(1234)    % seed
>> myrand(5)       % generate 5x1 vector
ans =
   228
   213
   217
    54
    16
>> myrand(3)
ans =
    37
   170
   188
>> clear myrand    % unload MEX-file from memory
>> myrand(1234)    % seed with the same number
>> myrand(5)       % generates same sequence as before
ans =
   228
   213
   217
    54
    16
```

If you want, you could also prevent the MEX-function from being unloaded by using `mexLock` after seeding. But you'll have to expose a special syntax which eventually calls the corresponding `mexUnlock` (something like `myrand(-1)` or any negative size).